# How to break item and price with preg_match_all() or substr() or explode()?

Tags: php, regex

```
Galax RTX2060 1 Click 12GB OC .................729 GALAX GTX 1660 SUPER 1-CLICK OC 6GB ...679 GALAX RTX3050 8GB GDDR6 ......................450
```

I am thinking if I can split the string at each (product ...price):

1. Galax RTX2060 1 Click 12GB OC .................729
2. GALAX GTX 1660 SUPER 1-CLICK OC 6GB ...679
3. GALAX RTX3050 8GB GDDR6 ......................450

Then str_replace('.', ' ') -> Galax RTX2060 1 Click 12GB OC 729

Finally, explode() by 'last' space (before the price) to get

- array[0] = Galax RTX2060 1 Click 12GB OC
- array[1] = 729

```
preg_match_all('/...\d /', $input_lines, $output_array);
array(1 0 => array(3 0 => .729 1 => .679 2 => .450 ) )
```

```
 $pattern = '/(?P<digit>\d+) (?P<name>\w+)/';
 preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);
 array(5
 0   =>  array(5
 0   =>  2060 1
 1   =>  729 GALAX
 2   =>  1660 SUPER
 3   =>  679 GALAX
 4   =>  3050 8GB
 )
 digit   =>  array(5
 0   =>  2060
 1   =>  729
 2   =>  1660
 3   =>  679
 4   =>  3050
 )
 1   =>  array(5
 0   =>  2060
 1   =>  729
 2   =>  1660
 3   =>  679
 4   =>  3050
 )
 name    =>  array(5
 0   =>  1
 1   =>  GALAX
 2   =>  SUPER
 3   =>  GALAX
 4   =>  8GB
 )
 2   =>  array(5
 0   =>  1
 1   =>  GALAX
 2   =>  SUPER
 3   =>  GALAX
 4   =>  8GB
 )
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match_all()` can be made to work here:

```php
$input_lines = "Galax RTX2060 1 Click 12GB OC .................729 GALAX GTX 1660 SUPER 1-CLICK OC 6GB ...679 GALAX RTX3050 8GB GDDR6 ......................450";
preg_match_all('/\s*(.*?)\s*\.{3,}\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/', $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

This places the product descriptions and prices into two separate 1D arrays.

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

- `\s*` match optional leading whitespace
- `(.*?)` match and capture the product description
- `\s*` optional whitespace
- `\.{3,}` match ellipsis ... defined as 3 or more contiguous dots
- `\s*` more optional whitespace
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` match and capture the price as an integer or float

Comment: Thanks, dude! It works though I haven't go through the entire product catalog.
Can you explain briefly what \s*(.*?)\s*\.{3,}\s*(\d+) means so that I can further investigate on my own?

Comment: @busterSg I have added a description of what the regex is doing.